# gaussian noise param for gazebo_ros_imu

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what are the units of gaussianNoise here:

```
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
        <topicName>imu</topicName>
        <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
        <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
        <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
        <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
        <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
        <frameName>base_link</frameName>
      </plugin>
```

my imu doc tells me it has a Noise Density:< 0.14 mg/√Hz, how do I translate that to this plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335440/gaussian-noise-param-for-gazebo_ros_imu/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is its the sigma (standard deviation) so its the same units as the inputs.

https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/a5c968497ff2c3cc353daa03e12929b4dd3197b2/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_imu_sensor.cpp#L120

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0